# Dual boot win/kali - virtualize the linux partition

Tags: partition, windows, virtualization, kali-linux

I have one HDD. 2 partitions with Kali and Windows 8. GRUB is installed. Both OS work fine.

I want to remove my Kali partition, and get it as a VM in my Windows 8 partition (I'm using VMware workstation).

Is there a way to virtualize this Kali partition ? without damaging my windows 8 one ? Windows does not see the linux partition at all (at least with the Disk Manager, maybe another software is able to see it as GParted or EasyPart).

Another solution is to erase my Kali partition and re-extend my windows 8 one, but I'm afraid the windows 8 partition would not boot after it. And it's less fun doing this way.
But the Kali partition does not have important stuff that I want to keep/save. So if it's the only way to do it, I can format the kali partition.

Hope I'm understable enough and at the right place to ask this kind of question.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VMware Converter](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter&proxystylesheet=VMware_gsa_Site&site=VMware_Site_1&cc=www&cn=vmware&entqr=0&ud=1&num=20&output=xml_no_dtd&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=converter) to convert the partition to a VM. After that, you would still need to remove the Kali partition and extend your Windows partition.

If Windows doesn't see the Windows partition, try QTParted from a Knoppix LiveCD. When the partition is removed, you should be able to extend your Windows partition. I have done this several times, and I don't think extending a Windows partition has big risks associated with it. If you want to be really sure, take a backup first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said, Windows can't see the linux partition, so VMware converter will not see the partition (already tried). Do you mean I have to install VMware on Kali ? and then virtualize the partition ? Then I will have to save/transfer the iso ?

Comment: I think it's best if you first figure out why Windows doesn't see the partition. Unfortunately there is no Linux version of VMware converter.